# GCDWebServerFileResponse, knowing when file is no longer being used

Tags: gcdwebserver

I'm using GCDWebServer in a sandboxed MacOS desktop application.

I make a file available to a client using the `GCDWebServerFileResponse`, which works well.

However, some of the file resources are accessed via a Security Scoped Bookmark (because of the sandbox).

Before accessing the file I need to call `bookmarkURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and then once I finish using the file I need to balance it with a `bookmarkURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`.

The issue I have is that I don't currently know when the web server has finished the response and the file is free to to close off.

Are there any listeners I can attach, or keys I can observe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is likely to subclass `GCDWebServerFileResponse` and override `-close`. See docs in GCDWebServerResponse.h.